# IntelliJ IDEA and Pycharm are not starting

Tags: java, intellij-idea, pycharm, ide

I am using latest version of IntelliJ and Pycharm community edition. When I am trying to run these software, I get same error (Start Failed) message for both IDE:

```
Internal error. Please refer to https://jb.gg/ide/critical-startup-errors

com.intellij.ide.plugins.StartupAbortedException: Cannot start app
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lambda$start$15(StartupUtil.java:263)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:986)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniExceptionallyStage(CompletableFuture.java:1004)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.exceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2307)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.start(StartupUtil.java:262)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.bootstrap(Main.java:118)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:79)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:459)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:448)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:227)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:134)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:562)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:506)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:491)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:973)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:260)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:356)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:469)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:503)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

-----
Your JRE: 11.0.14.1+1-b2043.25 amd64 (JetBrains s.r.o.)
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1\jbr
```

For Pycharm:

```
Your JRE: 11.0.14.1+1-b2043.25 amd64 (JetBrains s.r.o.)
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.1\jbr
```

I am using Java 8 only. There is not Java 11 installed. OS is windows 10.

Comment: Please see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-238995 for the workaround.

Answer (score 4):

A restart of Windows NAT worked for me.
Open Windows PowerShell in Administration mode, & type these commands:

```
net stop winnat 
net start winnat
```

Comment: Why does it works?

Answer (score 1):

The issues could be that the port the IntelliJ use could be in use. Although, IntelliJ has a range of ports to select from. But for some reason it did not check next ports.
By running winnat commands the port may gets free for Intellij to use.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).